# Filtering entries in Excel with multiple connected data on adjacent column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm sorry if my title is confusing, I'm fairly new to excel.

Below is a sample image, basically what I want to do is be able to filter the Topics. But when I filter to see -- Climate Change for example -- it does not show that it is a topic for the "Duis vulputate tempus" book. Would like to ask how I can connect the Title to all the Topics related to it. Thank you all in advance.

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Your data is organized in a layout that focuses on presentation rather than function. The pretty white spaces that make the list easier to read are also preventing the functionality you want to achieve.

In order to sort and filter by Topic and not end up with a bunch of blank cells, you need to fill all the blank cells with their respective values for Author and Title. To do this quickly, follow these steps:

- Select the columns for Author and Title (the whole columns)
- Hit the F5 key or use Ctrl-G to open the "Go to" dialog
- click the **Special** button
- tick the option for **Blanks** and hit the OK button.

Now all the blank cells in the two columns are selected. Without changing this selection,

- type a = sign
- hit the up arrow key
- hold down the Ctrl key and hit **Enter**

Now all the previously blank cells contain a formula that references the cell above.

You can now copy the content of the two columns and use **Paste Special > Values** to replace the formulas with the respective values.

After that, you can filter or sort by topic.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.